# Scale table width to fit columns, without resizing columns to fit table

Tags: html, css, html-table, resize, overflow

I have a table placed inside a div wrapper and it has 4 columns with the following widths: 400px, 300px 300px, 300px (so total width of 1300px). The behaviour I'm looking for is for the table to scale horizontally thus triggering the overflow on it's parent wrapper:

```
.table-wrapper {
    width: 800px;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

table {
    min-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: separate;
}
```

The HTML for the table is:

```
<div class="table-wrapper">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td width="400px">Col 1</td>
            <td width="300px">Col 2</td>
            <td width="300px">Col 3</td>
            <td width="300px">Col 4</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

The behaviour it currently has is to readjust columns so that they all fit within the wrapper's 800px width. I've search the web for anything similar but to no avail (so far). Anyone have any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Can you create a mock on jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the width of your table to 1300px.

http://jsfiddle.net/4Eere/

```
.table-wrapper {
    width: 800px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    background: blue;
}

table {
    width: 1300px;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: separate;
}

td { background: red;}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know what the width of my table will be as data can be loaded dynamically into columns. It will have a min of 3 columns but an average of 10.